# I want an xquery function which returns current date and time along with milliseconds

Tags: date, time, xquery

I want an xquery function which returns current date and time along with milliseconds 
example:-03/07/2013 15:32:49:357,is there any inbuilt function for this

Answer (score 0):

The function current-dateTime() returns the current time including milliseconds, for example: 2008-05-07T18:12:23.593+03:00 where .593 represents the milliseconds.

Comment: The precision of the date/time might vary from one implementation to another, but should always be at least milliseconds (it might be more).